# How to trigger callback function when input

Tags: user-input

I'm trying to write a simple plugin that let user input something, and while inputing, the plugin echos the input text in real time.

So far the script shows result after Enter pressed:

```
function! Test()
  let curline = getline('.')
  call inputsave()
  let name = input('Enter name: ')
  call inputrestore()
  call setline('.', curline . ' ' . name)
endfunction
```

How to improve it to handle real time input? I searched for `:h input` but I don't see any typing callback.

**Update**

The `getchar` works, but the text input is not displayed, I need to see the text input and modify it, like the `input(message)` feature, is it possible?

```
function! s:getchar()
  let c = getchar()
  if c =~ '^\d\+$'
    let c = nr2char(c)
  endif
  return c
endfunction

" Interactively change the window title
function! InteractiveTest()
    let char = "s"
    while char =~ '^\w$'
        echo "input to change title"
        let char = s:getchar()
        let &titlestring=char
        redraw
    endwhile
endfunction
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you'll have to introduce a fake mode, loop on `getchar()`, and redraw as you type.

In lh-vim-lib, check the code that is using [`lh#ui#ask()`](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-vim-lib/blob/master/autoload/lh/ui.vim#L276). In my *modes* I update a kind of status line that is used for displaying check boxes or comboboxes.

You'll likely have to update something equivalent and your buffer if I understand correctly your question.

---

Regarding your edit, you have to build the titlestring as you type whilst you were only using the last character typed.

It's more like

```
" autoload/youplugin.vim

function! s:getchar() abort
  let c = getchar()
  if c =~ '^\d\+$'
    let c = nr2char(c)
  endif
  return c
endfunction

" Interactively change the window title
function! yourplugin#InteractiveTest() abort
  let orig = &titlestring
  let title = ''
  while 1
    echo "input to change title: ".title
    let char = s:getchar()
    if char == "\<bs>" && !empty(title)
      let title = title[:-2]
    elseif  strtrans(char) == char
      let title .= char
    elseif char == "\<cr>"
      return title
    elseif char == "\<esc>"
      " restore and return
      let &titlestring = orig
      return ''
    endif
    let &titlestring = title
    redraw
  endwhile
endfunction
```

Comment: The `getchar()` works, but there is a new problem, please see the updated post.